# Showing events for multiple eventSources depend on checkboxes' choice in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plone, fullcalendar

I'm adding the feature like in Solgema Fullcalendar - http://plone.org/products/solgema.fullcalendar/releases/2.1.2
(selecting and showing events with checkboxes selection)

My eventSourses look like:

```
eventSources: [
            ...
            {
                url: '/admin_schedule/get_schedule_db_recurring_events_on_daysweek/',//"<?echo $data_path?>",
                type: 'GET',
                data: {sch_teacher_id: sch_teacher_id},
                backgroundColor: 'red',
            }

        ],
```

And I want implement checkboxes for "filtering" events by teachers, checked in checkboxes. For beginning make just one checkbox (later make foreach cover)

```
<div class="box">
        <?php
        $js = 'onClick="rerender_schedule()"';
        echo form_checkbox('teacher', 'vika', FALSE, $js)." Vika";  
        ?>
</div>
```

By this code as I think, fullcalendar must call rerender_schedule() function which filters data from eventSource with **vika's sch_teacher_id**

If somebody could help with rerender_schedule() function, I will be thankful, because not good in ajax.

EDIT: (thanks to tocallaghan!). It's just a beginning right now.

1. My 3 checkboxes:

   ```
       $data = array(
           'name'        => 'teacher',
           'class'       => 'teacher',
           'id'          => 'teacher',
           'value'       => '128',
           'checked'     => FALSE,
           'style'       => 'margin:10px',
           );

       echo form_checkbox($data); echo "Вика";  

       $data = array(
           'name'        => 'teacher',
           'class'       => 'teacher',
           'id'          => 'teacher2',
           'value'       => '111',
           'checked'     => FALSE,
           'style'       => 'margin:10px',
           );

       echo form_checkbox($data); echo "Вася"; 

       $data = array(
           'name'        => 'teacher',
           'class'       => 'teacher',
           'id'          => 'teacher3',
           'value'       => '1',
           'checked'     => FALSE,
           'style'       => 'margin:10px',
           );

       echo form_checkbox($data); echo "Саша";
   ```
2. ajax on change them:

   ```
   $('.teacher').change(function (event) {
           events1.data.sch_teacher_id = $(this).val(); 
           events2.data.sch_teacher_id = $(this).val();
           events3.data.sch_teacher_id = $(this).val();
           $calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       });
   ```
3. vars for eventSourses:

   ```
   var events1 = {
       url: 'url1',
       type: 'GET',
       data: {sch_teacher_id: $('#teacher').val() },
       success: function (response) {
           return response;
       }
   };
   var events2 = {
       url: 'url2',
       type: 'GET',
       data: {sch_teacher_id: $('#teacher').val() },
       backgroundColor: 'green',
       success: function (response) {
           return response;
       }
   };
   var events3 = {
       url: 'url3',
       type: 'GET',
       data: { sch_teacher_id: $('#teacher').val() },
       backgroundColor: 'red',
       success: function (response) {
           return response;
       }
   };
   ```
4. my eventSources call

   ```
   eventSources: [
       events1,
       events2,
       events3
   ],
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your edit. You can return an array of events from your url endpoint, not just a single one. Also it seems like this is a new question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [refetchEvents](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/) , but be careful to update you data parameter before calling (otherwise it will remain the initially set value)

```
$('.CheckBoxClass').change(function () {
    events.data.sch_teacher_id = $(this).val();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
});
```

Edit: code to declare events object:

```
var events = {
    url: 'url',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { Id: $('#divId').val() },
    success: function (response) {
        return response;
    }
};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: events
});
```

Comment: tocallaghan, it becomes better, now ajax works good, but sch_teacher_id still old: $('.teacher').change(function (event) {
     event.sch_teacher_id = 128;
     $calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
 });

Comment: it is not the event parameter you should be changing but rather a reference to the events object you created when initialising the fullcalendar. Assuming this is called "events" you should replace event.sch_teacher_id = 128 with events.data.sch_teacher_id

Comment: It looks like you have created your event object anonymously, in order to reference it later on you need to create before you use it. Create an event object (var event = {url: 'url', type: 'Get'...}) and replace your {url: 'url', type: 'Get'...} with it

Comment: tocalan, look, it's because in the beginning of view: $(document).ready(function() {

   var $calendar = $('#calendar');
   ...
   var sch_teacher_id = "<?php echo $sch_teacher_id; ?>";
   

   $calendar.fullCalendar({...     so I think I set again value for sch_teacher_id from php: var sch_teacher_id = "<?php echo $sch_teacher_id; ?>"; But I can't assume it to be empty.

Comment: when replace event.sch_teacher_id to events.data.sch_teacher_id, get error: ReferenceError: events is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

events.data.sch_teacher_id = 128;//$(this).val();

Comment: But I use eventSources:[...] to generate events, tocalan. Do you suggest replace it with creating object (var event = {url: 'url', type: 'Get'...}) ? I don't understand how to implement var event at the time of using eventSources.

Comment: see edit for further clarification. You should be able to use eventSources also, the key is that you declare the events object first then set up you fullcalendar object using it, you then have access to the events.data.whateverParamToChange from the change() function of the checkbox

Comment: tocallan, thank you! You recomendation works. Could you see edit in my question? How merge 3 events into 1, 'cause really i have 20 events!