# Default event not shown up in Fullcalendar after onChange function

Tags: jquery, joomla, fullcalendar

Please check the code for your reference

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            editable: true,

            eventDrop: function(calEvent,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revetFunc) {
                var stDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, 'dd-MM-yyyyy');
                $.post('event_update.php',{'allday':allDay, 'event':calEvent.id, 'start':stDate}, function(response){
                    if(response.length > 0){
                       alert(response);
                       revertFunc();
                    }
            });
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            }

        });

        $('#project').change(function() {
            var filter = $('#project').val();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'json-events.php?filter='+filter);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
        });

    });

</script>
```

Scenario 1 :

Before implementation of onChange function, full calendar will display all the events.

Scenario 2 :

After implementation of onchange function (Event Filter), it will display the events if the user changed filter option. By default no events displayed. Please advice me how to fix it

Comment: check the developer tools and see if you are getting the correct data back in the request?

Comment: Is this code custom or from an extension? Have you tried anything yourself to solve the problem you have, which I'm still a little confused about. Can you please explain in more detail

Comment: @Lodder If i remove    $('#project').change(function() {
            var filter = $('#project').val();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'json-events.php?filter='+filter);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
        }); Then the fullcalendar will display all the events by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your calendar doesn't have an event source initially.

Remove

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'json-events.php?filter='+filter);
```

and instead put it in the initialisation:

```
events: json-events.php?filter='+filter
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it is not working ! :(  If i remove $('#project').change(function() { var filter = $('#project').val(); $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents'); $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'json-events.php?filter='+filter); $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents'); }); Then the fullcalendar will display all the events by default.

Comment: I don't see where you define the event source though?? So haw can it display all events by default..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the calendar to display all events initially (scenario 1??) you need to have an events parameter when you initialise fullcalendar (alternatively call the change event manually). Your on change filter will not get called until a change event occurs so when the page loads the calendar will be empty.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    events: json-events.php?filter='+filter
 });
```

The on change event should work but AFIK you can get rid of the rerenderEvents as the addEventSource should take care of this.

If you would like to change the filter parameter without removing and adding the event source each time see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13675373/1195949)